# How to access local files using Remote Desktop (RemoteApp) and VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, remote-desktop

I have a development that was created to be able to read XML files so that the user could search these files locally, currently I was asked to bring this application to RemoteApp and it works very well, but the only "issue" is that when the user presses the button to be able to search for the files, the window runs on the server and does not allow me to see locally.

I have access to the source code and I understand that from the statement that I show as follows

```
    documentoxml = New XmlDocument
    Dim strPath As String = myOpenDialog.FileName
    documentoxml.Load(strPath)
```

it goes and looks for where it is being executed and therefore shows the server. Obviously the route would be something like this for example

> C:\Users\Public\Documents

**Is there a way that the user can see these local files?** I am using Windows Server and Windows 10 as a client.

Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 4):

Well, remote desktop means that your client side computer is sending mouse clicks, and screen updates back and forth.

In other words, your code running on that remote server is no different then using TeamViewer, or anything else. A remote computer is not really any different then you sitting down at the keyboard and screen of that remote computer.

So, just like while you looking at this post on SO? That does not now out of the blue THEN allow the remote computer to mess around and grab or use files on your local computer.

There are two approaches here.

First up, often when you connect to the remote computer, you can ALSO share your local files and folders. But, this will often depend on how remote desktop was launched.

So, that would be this option(s):

[image]

So, unless the user has shared their drives, then of course some remote computer can't just out of the blue start using files on your computer.

The 2nd possible choice?

This would requite you install/write some code that would be installed on the CLIENT side computer. These so called RDP "channels" would allow your server side code to talk to the client side code, and thus do local operaitons on the local computer.

For example, we often in a windows form have a button to click on for a email, we then launch outlook, fill in the body text, attached a pdf, and then the usere can futher edit, and then send  the email.

Well, when running our applicaion via remote desktop, when you click on that same button, we launch outlook, fill out the body, and attach a pdf, but we launching the CLIENT SIDE version of outlook!! (so we use YOUR copy of outlook on YOUR desktop, and automate that version from vb.net. This is a amazing feature of RDP, but it does require that some software be installed on each client computer for this to work. however, once the custom RDP channel is installed on each client computer, then the remote server side code can do remote operations on the client side computer - EVEN if they not shared their files.

So, if users do/have/will shared their local drive, then you can use network path names to the client side computer, but this tends to be limited.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote session is using the user's normal credentials, you can use

```
Dim strPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

to get access to the Documents folder (and other virtual folders) in the user's roaming profile.

This isn't exactly what you've asked for, but it might be what you need.